# How to run varImp() after building a SVM model?

Tags: r

I built a SVM after tuning:

```
svm.model <- svm(y~., data=mydata, kernel = "radial", cost = 10, degree = 2, gamma = 0.01)
```

Then I would like to check the feature importance by using `varImp()` as below:

```
importance <- varImp(svm.model, scale=F)
# summarize importance
print(importance)
# plot importance
plot(importance)
```

However it didn't work. The error was returned as:

Error in UseMethod("varImp") :
no applicable method for 'varImp' applied to an object of class "c('svm.formula', 'svm')"

The following code worked, but the problem is I don't know how to keep gamma, cost, degree the same by using `train()`:

```
# Setup for cross validation
ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",   # 10fold cross validation
                     repeats=5,         # do 5 repetitions of cv
                     summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,   # Use AUC to pick the best model
                     classProbs=TRUE)


#Train and Tune the SVM
set.seed(1)
svm.tune <- train(x=xdata,
                  y=ydata,
                  method = "svmRadial",   # Radial kernel
                  tuneLength = 9,         # 5 values of the cost function
                  preProc = c("center","scale"),  # Center and scale data
                  metric="ROC",
                  trControl=ctrl)

importance <- varImp(svm.tune, scale=F)
print(importance)
plot(importance)
```

So I'd like to know how to check the feature importance in the right way. Thanks!